# Is there any system variable which contain rebol user.r directory?

Tags: rebol

Since user.r has changed directory depending on version, it is annoying for automatic script distribution which would depend on user.r not to know where it is. So is there any system variable which would tell it ?

Answer (score 0):

user.r is, as the name infers, for setting individual preferences, settings and often-used scripts. It is not designed as a "mini-registry" for distributed applications. Depending on user.r for automatic script distribution sounds a very dubious idea.

Comment: Every decent system or framework has a known repository for library and so a mean to locate it. This is indispensable when you built a large system either monolithic or splitted into distributed architecture.